# Connected refused when trying to hit kubernetes nodeport service using minikube in win10

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a very simple springboot service deployed on minikube in windows 10.

C:\Software\Kubernetes>kubectl get deployments

```
NAME                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
myspringbootserver   1/1     1            1           68m
```

C:\Software\Kubernetes>kubectl get service

```
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          49d
myspringbootserver   NodePort    10.110.179.207   <none>        9080:30451/TCP   6m50s
```

C:\Software\Kubernetes>minikube service myspringbootserver --url

```
http://192.168.99.101:30451
```

But when I try to hit the service from my chrome browser with url

```
http://192.168.99.101:30451/MySpringBootServer/heartbeat
```

getting connection refused exception.Not sure what is going wrong.Could anyone help to resolve it please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLO1W.png)

Comment: Can You connect to `http://192.168.99.101:30451`?

Answer (score 2):

Can you `curl` or `wget`  using the IP address of the pod?

For example `kubectl exec -it podname -- curl http://podip:9080/MySpringBootServer/heartbeat`

if not, ensure the path is correct

if yes, make sure the pod exists as an endpoint of the service

`kubectl get endpoints myspringbootserver`

there is a good debugging document regarding services here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/#debugging-services